# Issue with making a message be reacted to

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, client

Hello I have been having an issue with creating a command that will react to any message that includes hello in it. What I want the bot to do is see a sentence such as "Hello how is your day" then pick up hello and react with the waving emoji. The issue is that nothing happens no console error nothing. Please help me fix this error thank you.

My Code:

```
client.login(token);

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.includes() === 'hello')
    await message.react('');

});
```

Comment: Never mind I fixed it

Comment: You should post an answer explaining how you fixed it in case people see this in the future and have the same question

Answer (score 0):

This is not how the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method works. You should pass it the string as an argument and it will return a boolean. Try this:

```js
client.login(token);

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.includes('hello'))
    await message.react('');
});
```